# Employee table (Master and detail table)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-design, schema, history

I am wondering if it is okay to have master and detail table for employees?

As per requirments, data can filtered by department by country and by employee code on report level.

If employee's department or country code is changed then the changes will go in detail table and old record will be set to IS_ACTIVE = 'T'.

---------------------Master Table--------------------------------------

```
**EMPLOYEE_CODE**      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  NOT NULL, 
EMAIL                  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
FIRST_NAME             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
LAST_NAME              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
WORKING_HOURS          NUMBER
```

---------------------Detail Table--------------------------------------

```
**PK_USER_DETAIL_ID**     NUMBER,
FK_EMPLOYEE_CODE          VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
FK_GROUP                  NUMBER,
FK_DEPARTMENT_CODE        NUMBER,
FK_EMPLOYER_COUNTRY_CODE  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
FK_MANAGER_ID             VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
FK_ROLE_CODE              VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
START_DATE                DATE,
END_DATE                  DATE,
IS_ACTIVE                 VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
INACTIVE_DATE             DATE
```

---

Employee table will be linked with Timesheet table and for timesheet reports data can be filtered by department, country and by employee code.

**OPTION : I**

- Have one employee table with one Primary Key and create a new entry whenever department or role is updated for an employee.
- Add country and department code in the timesheet table.

--> This way i don't need to search employee table.

**OPTION : II**

- Have master and detail table.
- Add country and department code in timesheet table.

--> This way i don't need to search employee table plus i will have master detail table

**OPTION : NEW**

- Have master and detail table.
- Timesheet table will have EmpCode.
- If user move to new *location* or *change department* then Insert a new row in the detail table with the new dept Code and same Emp No.
- Update an old row and set the End Date field so if he changes his location or department then the End Date field needs to be updated.

Which one is a best option and is there any other better option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 3 - Please note that this option is useful only for the reports Point of View.

1. Whenever you insert the data, create a `De-Normalized` entry in a new table.
2. Whenever an entry will be updated, the `De-Normalized` entry will be updated in the new table.
3. The New Table will have all `De-Normalized` columns of Employee.
4. So while Performing the search, this will benefit you as the results will be calculated without using `Joins`. Thus, the access time will be reduced.
5. Records in the new table will be Created/Updated in The Insert/Update Trigger.

### Improvements in Option - 2 and Option 1

Don't create redundancy by adding duplicate columns.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example of denormalize table?

Comment: yes sure. The new table will have Group Name, Manager Name, Role Name instead of Group ID, Manager ID, Role ID. IN this way you can get rid of Joins during the reporting.

Comment: So i will have three tables Master, Details and Denormalize one?

Comment: @user63981 - Yes. The De-Normalized table will be used in case of reports only so as to quickly access the data for reports. I forgot to tell you one thing. Please check my `point 5` for `option 3`

Comment: I am just thinking that it might get complicated because if for an example there are two entries for one employee (EmpCode=’UK007’) in the de normalize table, one has department code ‘023’ and other record has deptCode = ‘024’ as it has been updated.<br> In the timesheet table there are five entries of this employee ‘UK007’ with different deptCode and i want to run a report on the timesheet table where EmpCode = ‘UK007’ and DeptCode = ‘023’. How would system filter the rows on my criteria if there is no deptcode in the timesheet table?

Comment: How can an employee have two codes? and Time Sheet entry will be inserted/Updated on the basis of Date. Right?

Comment: Employee can move from one department to other. Yes timesheet entry will have inserted date with empcode and some other fields.

Comment: Once the employee is moved to another department then his/her ID will be changed and hence the code also. BUT the code will not be inserted . It will be updated.

Comment: did you you mean that we will create a new employee and set him to a different existing department? From reporting point of view, system should display the relavent dept code at the time user was filling timesheet and i think it would still require joining timesheet and employee table. what do you think?

Comment: In master table. Rest of the table should have merely Employee id.

Comment: Yes. That's good. It should not have any null/Duplicate value.

Comment: I am bit confuse now, if i run a report on the timesheet table then i would still require to join denormalize table? Unless dennormalize table has timesheet data as well.

Comment: pls check my question again as i have updated it with the New option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12741/discussion-between-user1263981-and-kanavi)

Answer (score 4):

This is one way of implementing this requirement, and it's an approach many people take.  However, it has on emajor drawback: every time you query the *current* employee status you need to filter the details on start and end date.  This may seem like a trivial thing, but you wouldn't believe how much confusion it can cause, and it has performance implications too.

These things matter, because most of the time you will want only the current details, with queries on history being a relatively rare occurence.  Consequently you are hampering the implementation of your most common use case to make it easier to implement a less-used one.  (Of course I am making assumptions about your business requirements, and perhaps yours is not a run-of-the-mill employee application...)

The better solution would be to have two tables, an EMPLOYEES table with all the detail columns too and an EMPLOYEES_HISTORY table with the same columns plus the start and end date.  When you change an employee's record insert a copy of the old record in the History table, probably by a trigger.  Your standard processes have just the one table to query, and your history needs are met fully.

---

By the way, your proposed data model is wrong.  Working_hours, email_address and last_name are definitely things which can change and perhaps even first name (e.g. through changes in personal circumstances such as getting married).  So all those columns should be held in your details name

Comment: Yes those columns can be changed but are not required in tracking history.

Comment: Frankly that seems bizarre but I suppose there's no accounting for business logic!

Comment: This is not a HR database and we are saving employee details just on certain level.